# JQuery animate callback not working in loops

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

I have a post list manipulated by jquery, when deleting one or more of the post row(s) in the table, I want the row(s) to fadeOut gradually then being removed from DOM, the code for deleting one row is as follows:

```
$('.post#' + postID).parent('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.post#' +postID).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

and it works perfectly for single row deletion, but when I put the above section of code in a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < selectedPostIds.length; i ++) {
    $('.post#' + selectedPostIds[i]).parent('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.post#' + selectedPostIds[i]).parent('tr').remove();
    });
}
```

The animation still works, but the DOM elements, i.e. the post rows didn't get removed. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the wrong use of a closure variable in a loop.

Inside the callback `this` refers to the `tr` element, so you can use

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedPostIds.length; i++) {
    $('.post#' + selectedPostIds[i]).parent('tr').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Also see

- [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

Comment: Worked great! Oh well, you saved me from hours of struggling, thanks truly for that! I noticed that jslint gived an warning says: "Don't make functions within a loop. " Any reason why this pops up and how to get rid of it?